# Recommendation when using bloc pattern in flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

When using flutter bloc what is the recommendation, is it recomended for each page to have its own bloc or can i reuse one block for multiple pages, if so how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to have one BLoC per page. It helps you to always know in which state each screen is just by looking at its BLoC. If you want to show the state of each of your tabs independently you should create one BLoC for each tab, and create one Repository which will handle fetching the data. But if the state of every tab will be the same, (for example you fetch data only once for all of the screens, so you don't show loading screen on every tab) then I think that you could create just one BLoC for all of this tabs.

It is also worth to add, that BLoCs can communicate with each other. So you can get state of one BLoC from another, or listen to its state changes. That could be helpful when you decide to create separate BLoCs for tabs.

I have addressed this topic in my [latest article](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/flutter-bloc). You can check it out if you want to dive deeper.

Comment: If we have one Bloc per page, how we can use Bloc state for different API calls in the page? for example maybe we have 3 API calls in one page. we can't use state for all 3 APIs

Answer (score 4):

There are no hard-set rules about this. It depends on what you want to accomplish.

An example: if each page is "radically" from each other, then yes, a `BLoC` per page makes sense. You can still share an "application-wide" `BLoC` between those pages if some kind of sharing or interaction is required between the pages.

In general, I've noticed that usually a `BLoC` "per page" is useful as there are always specific things related for each page that you handle within their `BLoC`. You can the use a general `BLoC` to share data or some other common thing between them.

You can combine the `BLoC` pattern with [RxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) to handle somewhat more complex interaction scenarios between a `BLoC` and the UI.

Sharing a `BLoC` is fairly simple, just nest them or use a `MultiProvider` (from the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)):

```dart
runApp(
    BlocProvider(
      builder: (_) => SettingsBloc(),
      child: BlocProvider(
        builder: (_) => ApplicationBloc(),
        child: MyApp()
      )
    )
);
```

and then you can just retrieve them via the `Provider`:

```dart
class MyApp extends ... {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final settingsBloc = Provider.of<SettingsBloc>(context);
    final appBloc = Provider.of<ApplicationBloc>(context);

    // do something with the above BLoCs
  }
}
```

Comment: My scenarion is that i have  five tabs, three of the tabs have the same list<datatype> but from different categories but the other two have different List<datatype>

Comment: @user2293554 ok, so a simplified solution (without knowing the details) would be to create an overarching `BLoC` that has the data needed for the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You can share different bloc's in different pages using BlocProvider.

Let's define some RootWidget that will be responsible for holding all Bloc's.

```
class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootPageState createState() => _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  NavigationBloc _navigationBloc;
  ProfileBloc _profileBloc;
  ThingBloc _thingBloc;

  @override
  void initState(){
    _navigationBloc = NavigationBloc();
    _thingBloc = ThingBloc();
    _profileBloc = ProfileBloc();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => _navigationBloc
          ),
          BlocProvider<ProfileBloc>(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => _profileBloc
          ), 
          BlocProvider<ThingBloc>(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => _thingBloc
          ),
    ],
      child: BlocBuilder(
        bloc: _navigationBloc,
        builder: (context, state){
          if (state is DrawProfilePage){
            return ProfilePage();
          } else if (state is DrawThingsPage){
            return ThingsPage();
          } else {
            return null
          }
        }
      )
    )
  }
}
```

And after that, we can use any of bloc from parent and all widgets will share the same state and can dispatch event on the same bloc

```
class ThingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ThingsPageState createState() => _ThingsPageState();
}

class _ThingsPageState extends State<ThingsPage> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    _profileBloc = BlocProvider.of<ProfileBloc>(context);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
        child: BlocBuilder(
          bloc: _profileBloc,
          builder: (context, state){
            if (state is ThingsAreUpdated){
              return Container(
                  Text(state.count.toList())
              );
            } else {
              return Container()
            }
          }
      )
    );
  }
}
```